# Connect Kentico through Azure SQL

Tags: azure, kentico

I've followed this tutorial https://docs.kentico.com/k12sptutorial/mvc-development and successfully run it on localhost, however when I try to publish to Azure app service the connection string doesn't seem to work at all and I've tried all the fixes including changing region of all services to be in one region, whitelist IP addresses.

here is the link of the site: 
https://adia.azurewebsites.net
[image]

connection string:

`Data Source=tcp:adiadb.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=adia;User Id=sqladmin@adiadb;Password=password`

[image]

Please advice when went wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting an error at all? If you try connecting using SQL management studio or just some C# code, does the connection open?

Comment: I'm having connection string error as you can see if you follow the link https://medioclinic20190929044926.azurewebsites.net. And yes, all the connection is open because I can connect it through SQL management tool.

Comment: I’m not getting a connectionstring error there. I see: “This site cannot be reached.”

Comment: Sorry I made typo and rectified the link, though I've attached the screenshot in the question

Comment: What happens if you re-start the AppService? Did the `CMSWaitForDatabaseAvailable` configuration flag have any impact?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the DB is not available to other resources within Azure. You’re able to connect with SQL Management Studio, but not the Web application. When you create the database, there is a checkbox to make it available to other resources within Azure. By default this is disabled. I’m not at my computer just now, but I’ll update this when I am with a screenshot of where to check.

Comment: Thanks Matt, that was what I thought and I've checked that option but still no luck. I've updated my question to reflect my latest effort.